# Need help writing the case statement - MySQL Cursor

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I created two columns in student table for my database. I now need to create a cursor for the student table. I need to make use of the input parameters for start and end student Id’s to filter the results in the cursor query.
I also need to open the cursor created and check if the student has an email assigned or not. If the email is not assigned I need to update the email column to have an email assigned to the student.

Finally to why I want help:
I cannot figure out how I would write the case statements for this cursor. I have tried to think of a good way to do this and not succeeded. Please help!!

```
DELIMITER $

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS CURSOR_DEMO$

CREATE PROCEDURE CURSOR_DEMO(start_student_id   INT
                            ,end_student_id     INT
                            ) 
BEGIN

DECLARE l_table_name    VARCHAR(50);
DECLARE iam_done    INT DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE l_sql_stmt  VARCHAR(5000);


 SET @l_sql_stmt='ALTER TABLE STUDENT ADD EMAIL VARCHAR';
    SELECT @l_sql_stmt;
    prepare stmt from @l_sql_stmt;
    execute stmt;


 SET @l_sql_stmt='ALTER TABLE STUDENT ADD PHONE int(10)';
    SELECT @l_sql_stmt;
    prepare stmt from @l_sql_stmt;
    execute stmt;

 DECLARE TBL_CUR CURSOR FOR
    SELECT EMAIL FROM STUDENT.TABLES WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA='MYSQLDB';



BEGIN

DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET IAM_DONE=1;



    OPEN TBL_CUR;



        tbl_loop:LOOP
            FETCH tbl_cur INTO l_table_name;        

                IF IAM_DONE = 1 THEN

                    LEAVE tbl_loop;

                END IF;


                CASE WHEN l_table_name = 'STUDENT' THEN



                ELSE BEGIN END;                     


                END CASE;                       



        END LOOP tbl_loop;

    CLOSE TBL_CUR;

END;

END$

DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this the kind of thing you need?

```
/*
drop table student;
delimiter $$
CREATE TABLE `student` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL ,
  `name` char(1) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(1),
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=8 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8$$

drop table email;
delimiter $$

CREATE TABLE `email` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL ,
  `type` varchar(8) NOT NULL,
  `person_id` int,
  `email` varchar(1),
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=8 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8$$
;
*/
DELIMITER $
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS CURSOR_DEMO$
CREATE PROCEDURE CURSOR_DEMO(start_student_id   INT
                            ,end_student_id     INT)
BEGIN

declare email_person_id int;
declare email_address   varchar(50);
DECLARE done    INT DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE CUR CURSOR FOR
    SELECT person_id,email FROM sandbox.email where type = 'student';
DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done=1;

    OPEN CUR;
        cur_loop:LOOP
                IF done = 1 THEN
                    LEAVE cur_loop;
                END IF;
                FETCH CUR INTO email_person_id,email_address;   
                update  student
                set     email = email_address
                where   id = email_person_id
                    and email is null
                ;
        END LOOP cur_loop;
    CLOSE CUR;
    commit;
END$
DELIMITER ;
truncate table student;
insert into student
values
(1,'A','1'),
(2,'B','1'),
(3,'C',null),
(4,'D',null),
(5,'E',null),
(6,'G',null),
(7,'F',null)
;
truncate table email;
insert into email
values
(1,'student',1,'a'),
(2,'student',2,'b'),
(3,'faculty',7,'z'),
(4,'student',3,'c')
;

select * from student;

call cursor_demo(1,10);

select * from student;
```

Comment: Cursors are a method of last resort, you should use an update statement rather than a cursor if you can.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. email is a column and not a table. And I did use alter to create a column each for email and phone.

Comment: To be honest I couldn't figure out what you are trying to achieve in this procedure for the following reasons:- the inclusion of the alter statements means this procedure is not reuseable (which is the point of a procedure) - but may have been your intent, the procedure did not syntax (all declares have to be at the start of a begin block and the tbl_cursor declaration is not) and the select into the cursor doesn't make sense. I also could not see where you were getting the email address to update the student record. It might help if you published the tables you have and your desired output.